# How can I modify the image color to remove some color?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, jpg

I have an image like this one:

[image: Sample background image]

Is there a way that I can modify the colors of this image to remove some blue and make it into an image with just shades of grey?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily in Photoshop:

---

From the top toolbar select **Images > Adjustments > Black & White**

From here you can play around with the presets to get the effect you want.
[image: Images > Adjustments > Black & White]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove *some* of the blue and decrease the overall saturation... choose `Image > adjustments > Hue/Saturation` and move the **Saturation** slider to the left. The father left you move it, the more grey the image will get.

[image]